# Is it possible to capturing video in background mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on a task in which there is a video recording feature that works in background mode. There is a flow where user can click or shake the phone and video capturing starts in background mode for sometime. I have searched some links, however there is no reference to this kind of feature.

Any suggestion please...

Comment: So what can I do to achieve this feature....??

Comment: No I don't think so Apple provides any such feature for background mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve it. Camera process will be suspended or killed when the app will moved to background.